# MVC C# URL rewriting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

I have a problem after URL rewriting.
My URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:50564/Product/ProductDetails/Audi-50%20(86)-1.1/Set%20placute%20frana/77455DE7%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B
```

But, if I change the parameter `id` "77455DE7" from the URL with an existing product id from the database, I get error 404. It should load me the details page with that product.

[image]

I don't know why this is happening. Can you give me some hints what to try in order to resolve this?

I use this route:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Detail",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{selected}/{category}/{code}‌​",
  defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetails", selected = UrlParameter.Optional, category = UrlParameter.Optional, code = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have this `href`:

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product" , new { selected=@selectedCar, category=@c.Name, code=@c.Code})" id="link">
   Details
</a>
```

Also, in my URL there is the `%E2%80%8B` white space. I try to resolve with

```cs
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code);
```

I've tried to resolve with `Trim`, `Replace("%E2%80%8B", string.Empty)`. Nothing has resolved this problem.

Comment: You should neither use `HtmlEncode` for your urls if you use Razor nor talk about "url rewriting". There is routing in ASP.NET MVC. Do you have routes set up, and do you use the `Url.*` helpers to generate your urls?

Comment: Remove all `@`s from `selected=@selectedCar, category=@c.Name, code=@c.Code`. And obviously all the values must not be already HTML encoded, they must be raw values.

Comment: I've tried what you have suggested, but it did not resolve the problem. <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product" , new { selected=selectedCar, category=c.Name, code=c.Code})" id="link">
   Details
</a> The values are not encoded now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test is correctly. Your solution resolved the problem. Now it works. The page is loaded if I enter a valid product id. The white space problem still persist, do you have any idea what can I try? The Replace, Trim did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Apparently you have white space as part of the id in the database.

Comment: It's interesting. I've tried to put a slash at the end of the URL, and now it looks like this: http://localhost:50564/Product/ProductDetails/Filtru-combustibil-Audi-50%20(86)-1.1/DB3D5114/%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B. In the route I put this way: url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}-{selected}/{code}/‌​".  It seems that the problem is not coming from DB.

Comment: U+200B is the [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). Apparently you have one in the route code which you cannot see because it's zero width. Delete the `/{code}",` part entirely, with the quote and the comma, then retype it.

Comment: Thanks!!! the white space does not appear anymore. I resolved with your solution. Thanks again!